Why are the posts overlapped everytime there is a change to database?
I am trying to build a social media system on react native where the users get real time update of the posts. However, the posts are overlapping in Flatlist and i have checked the key extractor id and everything. The following is the home.jsx component
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, FlatList, Pressable, Alert, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../../context/AuthContext';
import { supabase } from '../../lib/supabase';
import Avatar from '../../components/Avatar';
import { router } from 'expo-router';
import { fetchPosts } from '../../services/postService';
import PostCard from '../../components/PostCard';
import Loading from '../../components/Loading';
import { getUserData } from '../../services/userService';

const Home = () => {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10); // Keep track of limit as state

  const handlePostEvent = async (payload) => {
    if (payload.eventType === 'INSERT' && payload?.new?.id) {
      let newPost = { ...payload.new };
      let res = await getUserData(newPost.userId);
      newPost.user = res.success ? res.data : {};
      setPosts((prevPosts) => [newPost, ...prevPosts]); // Add new posts at the top
    }
  };
  
  const getPosts = async (isRefreshing = false) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetchPosts();
      if (response.success) {
        if (isRefreshing) {
          setPosts(response.data); // Overwrite posts if refreshing
        } else {
          setPosts((prevPosts) => {
            const newPosts = response.data.filter(
              newPost => !prevPosts.some(post => post.id === newPost.id)
            );
            return [...prevPosts, ...newPosts]; // Append only new posts
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
    }
  };

  const onRefresh = async () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    await getPosts(true); // Pass true to indicate refresh
    setRefreshing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let postChannel = supabase
      .channel('posts')
      .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'posts' }, handlePostEvent)
      .subscribe();
    
    getPosts();

    return () => {
      supabase.removeChannel(postChannel);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1">
      <View className="mx-5 flex-1">
        {/* Header */}
        <View className="flex-row justify-between my-8 items-center">
          <Text className="text-2xl font-psemibold text-gray-600">Hello, {user && user.name}</Text>
          <Pressable onPress={() => router.push('/profile')}>
            <Avatar uri={user && user.image} size={50} rounded={30} />
          </Pressable>
        </View>

        {/* Posts */}
        <FlatList
          data={posts}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 20, paddingHorizontal: 4 }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
              <PostCard item={item} currentUser={user} router={router} />
            </View>
          )}
          ListFooterComponent={
            <View style={{ marginVertical: posts.length === 0 ? 200 : 30 }}>
              <Loading />
            </View>
          }
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;

For correct styling, I have to manually restart the whole application in expo with npx expo start.
